# Python cant seem to connect to SDK

Tags: python, pip, py-langchain

Ive been trying to download Langchain for a while now (10ish) hours and i think i exausted every troubleshooting online, pip just doesn't work. I have already uninstalled and re-installed Python and Visual C++, change virtual enviorements, etc. For a while i was having problem for it to detect io.h because it was trying to find it in pythons own include folder instead of in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" even WITH the INCLUDE in envioremental variables as the number one priority, it would still try on its own folder.

I solved it after a while and needed to add every single folder and sub-folder of Include to env-variables as INCLUDE and every single one of "Windows Kits\10\Lib" subfolders as well (as LIB)

But now, the following error is emerging and i cant even understand whats going on:

```
> _frozenlist.obj : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_free
> _frozenlist.obj : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_malloc
> MSVCRT.lib(dll_dllmain.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido _initterm
> MSVCRT.lib(dll_dllmain.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido _initterm_e
> MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_RtlCaptureContext
> MSVCRT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_RtlCaptureContext
> MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_RtlLookupFunctionEntry
> MSVCRT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_RtlLookupFunctionEntry
> MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_RtlVirtualUnwind
> MSVCRT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_RtlVirtualUnwind
> MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_UnhandledExceptionFilter
> MSVCRT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_UnhandledExceptionFilter
> MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_SetUnhandledExceptionFilter
> MSVCRT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_SetUnhandledExceptionFilter
> MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_GetCurrentProcess
> MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_TerminateProcess
> MSVCRT.lib(gs_report.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_IsProcessorFeaturePresent
> MSVCRT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_IsProcessorFeaturePresent
> MSVCRT.lib(gs_support.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_QueryPerformanceCounter
> MSVCRT.lib(gs_support.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_GetCurrentProcessId
> MSVCRT.lib(gs_support.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_GetCurrentThreadId
> MSVCRT.lib(gs_support.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_GetSystemTimeAsFileTime
> MSVCRT.lib(dll_dllmain_stub.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_DisableThreadLibraryCalls
> MSVCRT.lib(tncleanup.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_InitializeSListHead
> MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido _seh_filter_dll
> MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido _configure_narrow_argv
> MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido _initialize_narrow_environment
> MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido _initialize_onexit_table
> MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido _register_onexit_function
> MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido _execute_onexit_table
> MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido _crt_atexit
> MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido _crt_at_quick_exit
> MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido _cexit
> MSVCRT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_IsDebuggerPresent
> MSVCRT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_GetStartupInfoW
> MSVCRT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido __imp_GetModuleHandleW
> MSVCRT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido terminate
> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\frozenlist\_frozenlist.cp312-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 31 externo nÆo resolvidos
> error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
```

At this point, i have tried to re-install my Visual Studio Build and Python, together with upgrading pip, tools, wheels, etc. I've put Pythons, VS Build, and SDK on path, with everything manually added on "Windows Kit" in their respective path too (INCLUDE or LIB)

Ive searched a lot on the last 10 hours of troubleshooting but every solution i tried didn't really work, maybe the problem is Windows 11? Every post i could find was still talking about Windows 10.
I suspect it still has something to do with Python not connecting to it's c++ header/libraries correctly, but idk what to do about it